# Angular 4 Elasticsearch Observable and Ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, angular2-observables

I know that the Elasticsearch js client is designed to return Promises and Angular 4+ uses Observables for http requests. So I'm trying to figure out how I can use Ng-bootstrap Typeahead with Elasticsearch. Do I use Observables or promises?

The ES client is going to return a promise from what I understand in my searchService. So how would I convert the return that the ES client gives me to an Observable pattern in my component code?

OR is there a way to use Observables with the ES client in my searchService? I've tried a few things, but not much is working...

My component so far...

```
    export class AutocompleteComponent {
  pageTitle = 'Autocomplete'; // for page title

  // these 4 are NgbBootstrap Typeahead example
  model: any;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;
  hideSearchingWhenUnsubscribed = new Observable(() => () => this.searching = false);

  private _queryText = '';

  // private searchService:SearchService, private esService:Elasticsearch2Service
  constructor(private title:Title, private searchService:SearchService) {
    //this._queryText = '';
  }

  // this is NgbBootstrap Typeahead example
  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  //fullTextSearch = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$
      .debounceTime(300)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .do(() => this.searching = true)
      .switchMap(term =>
        //this.searchService.search(term)
        Observable.fromPromise(this.searchService.search())
          .do(() => this.searchFailed = false)
          .catch(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return Observable.of([]);
          }))
        .do(() => this.searching = false)
        .merge(this.hideSearchingWhenUnsubscribed);
```

Most of the component code is taken straight from their Wikipedia http example.

My searchService so far...

```
    // search function aka autocomplete
  search(term: string) {
    if (term === '') {
      return Observable.of([]);
    }

    //https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-http-get-parameters-headers-urlsearchparams-requestoptions-example
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.append('q', term);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders, params: myParams});

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    return this.client.search({
      index: 'query-index',
      type: 'autocomplete',
      filterPath: ['hits.hits._source', 'hits.total'],
      body: {
        "query": {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "suggestion": {
              "query": term
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "size": 5,
      "from": 0,
      "_source": ['suggestions']
    }).then(function(es_return) {
      deferred.resolve(es_return);
    }, function(error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

Most of this code comes from AngularJS 1.x searchService. Trying to figure out how to convert it to make useable with Angular 4+.

Comment: you are already using `Observables.fromPromises` what is the problem you get using them

Comment: @RahulSingh, the error says that NgFor needs an array to iterate over. Its receiving an object. I'm not sure how to give NgFor the array that it wants. Still trying to get my head around Observables. I'm using Elasticsearch and the JS client returns promises... so that has me pretty confused at how to convert what the component receives into something it can use?